# SQL table Partitioning by Year with ColumnStore index implemented on the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

SQL Server 2014

I have developed a **SSIS package** to load data to one **DW database**.

Below is my understanding -

> 1. Create Main table with **Clustered index + ColumnStore index  + PARTITIONING TABLE BY DATE**
> 2. Create Staging table with same Clustered Index and in same File Group
> 3. Load current date data to staging table using SSIS Package job run
> 4. After loading data in staging table, create columnstore index same as Main Table
> 5. Add current date range to Main table, which creates partition for current date
> 6. Using SWITCH command --> Switch Staging table to above created Current Date Partition ( PS : I understand that this command works
>      fine, though Column Store index is enabled on Main Table, there is no
>      need to rebuild the index.)

Now, I think that above is the best practice for partition by date with column store index.

However, there is a requirement to implement Partition by YEAR.

How can I design this structure and implement partition to fulfill below requirements ?

> • Partition should be done by YEAR
>
> • SSIS Package will  load around 1M rows for each current day to the
>   table.
>
> • Column Store index should be implemented on Main table to query
>   data. (As table size is going to be huge)
>
> • Does staging table require in this case? If yes, then for switching
>   data to partition of year, we have to wait until whole one year of
>   data to be loaded to Staging table ?? I don't see this option
>   feasible.
>
> • There are 4 local disks and total size is around 2TB. How many file
>   groups I should create according to the partitioning by year, so that
>   one active transaction query should perform best ?
>
> • Is it good to have one Clustered columnstore index on the Main table? As I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2014. I forgot to mention that. Let me add that in Question. Thank you.